# Building and deploying plugins to directories within Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, mef

We have a .NET 4 app, that has a main body, and looks in a specific subdirectory for plugins to load with MEF.

Right now, for system testing I have a top level solution that builds the main app and plugins, and the plugins are placed in the subdirectory with an "XCOPY" post build event.

Now this is... ok but it seems a little hacky to me, and there are various issues with this.

So my question is - is there a better way to do this? Surely there is a way I can work within visual studio to structure my build correctly?

Thanks in advance for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Set the output directory of the plugin projects to the plugin directory. You can do this in the properties of the project, in the build tab. This way you can also debug your plugins very easily!

Comment: If I do that though, the plugin project is now dependant on the path to the solution it's in... I guess I was hoping to be able to tailor this in the solution, and leave the plugin nice and isolated.